# PHP Sessions not saved

Tags: php, session, mamp

My sessions aren’t working. Everytime I reload the page it generates a new session id and deletes
all session variables.. I am not sure if there is an error in my code or in my configuration.
I am using MAMP on Mac as local server software with php 5.2.17

Every php file includes the layout_top.php at first. 
the layout_top starts the session every time:

```
<?php

        session_start();

    ?>
```

also there is a log in site like this:

```
<?php

include 'layout_top.php';

include 'db_connect.php';

$username = $_POST["li_username"]; 
$pw = $_POST["li_passwort"];

    if ($username == "" || $pw == "") {
        echo "Fülle bitte alle Felder aus!";
        }

    else {

        $check_pw_query = mysql_query("SELECT password FROM user WHERE username = '$username'") or die(mysql_error());

        $check_pw = mysql_fetch_assoc($check_pw_query);

        if ($pw == $check_pw{'password'}) {
            echo "Juhu! </br>";



            $first_name_query = mysql_query("SELECT first_name FROM user WHERE username = '$username'") or die(mysql_error());

            $first_name = mysql_fetch_assoc($first_name_query);

            $second_name_query = mysql_query("SELECT second_name FROM user WHERE username = '$username'") or die(mysql_error());

            $second_name = mysql_fetch_assoc($second_name_query);        

            $id_query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM user WHERE username = '$username'") or die(mysql_error());

            $id = mysql_fetch_assoc($id_query);

            if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            }

            if (!isset($_SESSION['first_name'])) {
                $_SESSION['first_name'] = $first_name{'first_name'};
            }    

            if (!isset($_SESSION['second_name'])) {
                $_SESSION['second_name'] = $second_name{'second_name'};
            }

            if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
                $_SESSION['id'] = $id{'id'};
            }
            if (!isset($_SESSION['gender'])) {
                $_SESSION['gender'] = $gender{'gender'};
            }

        }

    }
```

There it sets the session variables.. but if I reload the page all session variables are gone.
Hope you understand my problem.
Thanks for helping.

EDIT: Here is the phpinfo(), maybe this will help finding the problem..

```
session.auto_start          Off Off
session.bug_compat_42   On  On
session.bug_compat_warn On  On
session.cache_expire    180 180
session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
session.cookie_httponly Off Off
session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
session.cookie_path /   /
session.cookie_secure   Off Off
session.entropy_file    no value    no value
session.entropy_length  0   0
session.gc_divisor  100 100
session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440
session.gc_probability  1   1
session.hash_bits_per_character|4   4
session.hash_function   0   0
session.name            PHPSESSID|PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value    no value
session.save_handler    files   files
session.save_path   /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php  /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.use_cookies On  On
session.use_only_cookies    Off Off
session.use_trans_sid   0   0
```

EDIT 2:

```
Strict Standards: session_start() [function.session-start]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. Please use the date.timezone setting, the TZ environment variable or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Europe/Berlin' for 'CET/1.0/no DST' instead in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/network/layout_top.php on line 6

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/network/layout_top.php:1) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/network/layout_top.php on line 6

Strict Standards: session_start() [function.session-start]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. Please use the date.timezone setting, the TZ environment variable or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Europe/Berlin' for 'CET/1.0/no DST' instead in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/network/layout_top.php on line 6

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/network/layout_top.php:1) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/network/layout_top.php on line 6
```

Comment: `mysql_*()` API are deprecated. Use either the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension instead. [Deprecated mysql_*()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)

Comment: i know.. i just started with php so i will learn this in the near future! but thanks for telling me :)

Comment: your timezone strict standards warning outputs text to screen and that leads to session_start to fail because `...Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why you are taking so many queries... try this

```
       $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$username'") or die(mysql_error());

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($first_name_query))
        {

        if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
        }

        if (!isset($_SESSION['first_name'])) {
            $_SESSION['first_name'] = $row['first_name'];
        }    

        if (!isset($_SESSION['second_name'])) {
            $_SESSION['second_name'] = $row['second_name'];
        }

        if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
            $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
        }
        if (!isset($_SESSION['gender'])) {
            $_SESSION['gender'] = $row['gender'];
        }
        }
```

and I will **not suggest you to save multiple data on session** .. just save `userid` in your session variable, because **session variables are saved on server** so it puts load on your server..

If your session directory (most like /tmp as you said) is not writable, then it won't be able to save and will have to regenerate a new one each time. Here is how you can verify it:

`if ( !is_writable(session_save_path()) ) {
   echo 'Session save path "'.session_save_path().'" is not writable!'; 
}`

and if it is **not writable** than please change the **directory permissions**...

for **timezone** error.. 
please look at this link.. you need to `set default timezone`
http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

and for **header already sent error** please check
[How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

so you will be done.. :)

please let me know if you want any further guidance..

Comment: okay this makes sense! but this doesn't solve my problem. if i reload the page the session is gone and I have no idea why..

Comment: i never use destroy_session and unset in all included files.. just at a log-out.php but this shouldn't be the problem as this is a different file.. I think the problem is with MAMP's configuration but I couldn't find any thing

Comment: there is nothing in db_connect.php and it is writable, so this can't be the problem

Comment: put `ini_set('display_errors', 'on'); error_reporting(-1)` on the top of your code... and check which error it throws..

Comment: Please put the following code in layout_top.php : <?php
session_start();
echo session_id();
?> Access only layout_top.php in browser and check whether u r getting the same session id each time

Comment: <?php session_start(); ?> should be the first statement an nay page. It should come before HTML tag

Answer (score 0):

are you sure "layout_top.php" is actually included? Maybe a path problem, if you use `include` instead of `require` and you have disabled `error_reporting` then this problem can happen since the failure of inclusion will lead to warning, not error, and it wont display the warning message.

please add a line to your layout_top.php just **after** the `session_start` like this `echo "hello! session started!";` to see if session has started or just use `require` instead of `include` so in the case the file is not found your script will die with a fatal error.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of vague answer but sometimes it might do a little help.

Don't use `sesison_start()` on every file by including layout_top.php. Try to do a session start on a first load and then avoid calling `session_start()` again.